# Better approach to adding new CSV conversion method

Tags: java, design-patterns, class-design

Currently I have a class hierarchy for parsers with `Parser` as interface with `CSVParser` and `XMLParser` classes implementing it. The interface has following methods :
`List<AType>parse(File file)`

Now I want to add another parsing method that would take the same File type as the argument, but will return `List<BType>`. This method is required only for CSV type of files and not the for XML type files.
One simple option is to add a new method to the `Parser` interface with a different name. Also provide empty implementation in XMLParser file and the required method implementation in CSVParser. But some how I don't feel this is the right choice. I want to know what would be a better alternative choice?

Comment: And if you had a JSonParser, would you have both parsing methods or only the current one?

Comment: Another related question: how does the consuming class know that it's a CSVparser and that it sould use the second method?

Comment: Consuming class gets the parser instance from a factory class. The factory creates a parser instance based on the file extension that is being parsed

Comment: "This method is  - **currently(?)** - required only for CSV type of files"? But it could make sense, at least in principle (maybe in the future), for XML files? Then there is nothing wrong by providing an empty implementation in XMLParser ("empty" in the sense it throws a "NotImplementedException" exception), feels quite right for me.

Comment: Yes it is currently required only for CSV file types

Comment: @Innocuous: you missed my point, my question was if it could make sense in principle for XML files, even if you don't need it yet.

Comment: Well It is not needed for XML file types

Comment: @Innocuous: If the customer next asks to support the new method also for XML files, would you consider that request reasonable or absolutely crazy?

Comment: @Innocuous: yes, you already wrote that, but that was not my question. Please read my question again and try to clarify.

Comment: ... no clarification, so downvoting and voting to close as "unclear".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a perfect example for generics combined with the Template-Method pattern ([Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)):

```
public interface Parser<T> {
    List<T> parse(File file);
}

public abstract class CSVParser<T> implements Parser<T> {
    public List<T> parse(File file) {
        List<String[]> lines = loadCSV(file);
        return buildResult(lines)
    }
    public abstract List<T> buildResult(List<String[]> lines);
}

public class CSVParserAType extends CSVParser<AType> {
    public List<AType> buildResult(List<String[]> lines) {
        ...
    }
}

public class CSVParserBType extends CSVParser<BType> {
    public List<BType> buildResult(List<String[]> lines) {
        ...
    }
}

public class XMLParser implements Parser<AType> {
    public List<AType> parse(File file) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The generic type is used to keep the result type flexible to future implementations.

The Template-Method pattern is used to reuse csv-loading mechanism and ensure that it is done before building the result.

List of String[] contains the lines of the CSV-File separated in columns (String[], String-Array). If your CSV is huge, you may consider something like a cursor or a stream so you can abstract from the way how much data is actually read into memory to have a better memory footprint.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to add a second parser method in `CSVParser` that returns a different type?  Is this correct?  Then I'm assuming both of these methods would parse CSV files?

The problem derives from naming conflicts as I see it.  The way you structured your code, there is one `Parser` for each type of file, in this case an `XMLParser` for xml files and a `CSVParser` for csv files.  This is all fine and good if you will only have one said parser for each type of file, but apparently that is no longer your case.

While you *could* add a 2nd method in `Parser` and throw an `NotImplementedException` in the `XmlParser` second method, you have to really ask yourself if `XmlParser` is the exception to the rule or if it *is* the rule.  In other words, if tomorrow you decide to add yet another parser, will this new parser return both a list of `AType` as well as a list of `BType`?  In that case, `XmlParser` is the odd one out, and it may be a good idea to extend this behavior to `Parser`, but I'm guessing that isn't the case here.

Therefore it would most likely be a bad idea to add a 2nd method to `Parser`.  Thankfully there are alternatives!  Since a `Parser` implementation is no longer tied only to the type of file, a straightforward solution might be to have a `CSVToATypeParser` and a `CSVToBTypeParser`.  In this way, you can use either one as you would any other parser.

A second solution would be to combine `AType` and `BType` somehow as `CType` so that a call to `CSVParser` would return all the information you'd require from `AType` and `BType` in a single method.  Consider that you're still performing one pass regardless, so aside from a increase in memory usage, there would be no added disadvantage.

Hope that helps!